# Layer 2 QoS for Windows Server 2012 service

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, qos

We have an unmanaged Cisco SG102-24 switch which supports layer 2 QoS (IEEE 802.1p). Because we're installing VoIP at our office, we would like to prioritize VoIP packets from our voice server which is running Windows Server 2012 R2. How can we realize this?

I've already set the DSCP value for the voice service to 46 but this of course only works with layer 3 switches. In the group policy editor there are options for layer 2 QoS in the tab Administrative Templates > Network > QoS Packet Scheduler, where I can set priority values for certain priority types, like "ServiceTypeGuaranteed" or "ServiceTypeBestEffort". But where can I define which packet belongs to which service type?

Comment: I don't suppose getting a proper, managed switch is an option, is it?  I sure wouldn't attempt VOIP without it.

Comment: I prefer using the resources I already have. :-)

Comment: @android what voice server software are you running? I suppose the software should be responsible for the service type assignment

Comment: We're using 3CX Phone System.